# Minikube ClusterIP not reachable

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

i have created a deployment and a service to deploy an angular app. I'm using minikube and here is my deployment.yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: angular-deployment
spec:
  selector: 
    matchLabels:
      app: angular
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
     labels:
      app: angular
  spec: 
    containers:
    - name: angular
      image: dhartl231198/k3s-dashboard
      imagePullPolicy: Always
      ports:
      - containerPort: 80
```

---

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
 name: angular-service
spec:
 selector:
   app: angular
 ports:
 - protocol: TCP
   port: 8080
   targetPort: 80
 type: ClusterIP
```

the deployment is already reachable within the cluster but i cannot access it from my machine.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't exposed your `Service` to outside of your cluster. That's why you can't access the Service from your local machine.

Now, you have two options:

1. Make the Service type `NodePort`, then follow this [official minikube guide](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/).
2. Use `kubectl port-forward svc/angular-service :8080` on a terminal. Then, use the forwarded port to connect from the local machine.

Comment: thanks seems to work but now the app is reachable on port on a random port. Is it possible to set port 8080 in my deployment.yaml as the port where i can reach the service?

Comment: so if i just set it to Nodeport its still not accessable

Comment: ok i found the solution. The problem that i'm using docker as vm for my minikube. To fix this issue, you have to add the ports flag when starting minikube like this:

 % minikube start --driver=docker --ports=30080:30080 30081:30081